# How to turn an Object that may be an array or any Collection to a String?

Tags: java

I have an Object of which i know that it is either a Collection, something that extends Object[] or any primitive array, and I want to get its String-representation: `[e1, e2, ..., en]`

- `String.valueOf(object);` Doesn't work for arrays and foreign Collections with different `toString` methods.
- `object.getClass().isArray() ? Arrays.toString((Object[]) object) : String.valueOf(object);` Throws a ClassCastException when a primitive array gets passed.
- `"[" + Stream.of(object).map(v -> v.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "]";` Interprets the passed object as one element and creates a Stream of that.

I'm looking for a fast solution, preferably one that doesn't rely on libraries. And it shouldn't involve a gigantic if-else/switch block for type checking.

Comment: Sounds like you are only missing the check for a primitive array!?

Answer (score 0):

> an `Object` of which I know that it is either a `Collection`, something
> that extends `Object[]` or any **primitive array**

The overall problem statement sounds very smelly. Even if you didn't develop this code, but inherited from your predecessor, I strongly advise you to replace it with something more viable.

But you can deal with an array of arbitrary type using reflection:

```
int[] nums = {1, 2, 3};
Object arr = nums;

if (!(arr instanceof Collection<?>)) {
    int len = Array.getLength(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        System.out.println(Array.get(arr, i));
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: But isn't reflection slow as hell?

Comment: @xtay2 That's correct, have a look at the comment at the very beginning. Treat the data properly and you'll be fine.

Comment: Sadly, I have no effect on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class like `PrintTools` like this:

```java
public class PrintTools {
    
    public static String print(Collection c){
        return c.toString();
    }
    
    public static String print(Object... o){
        return Arrays.deepToString(o);
    }
    
}
```

So that you will be taken to a proper method depending on argument type.

So your test could be the following:

```java
public class TestPrintTools {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A[] a1 = {new A(1), new A(2)};
        int[] a2 = {3, 4};
        List<A> a3 = List.of(new A(5), new A(6));
        System.out.println(PrintTools.print(a1));
        System.out.println(PrintTools.print(a2));
        System.out.println(PrintTools.print(a3));
    }

}

class A{
    int a;

    public A(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
                "a=" + a +
                '}';
    }
}
```

with the output:

```
[A{a=1}, A{a=2}]
[[3, 4]]
[A{a=5}, A{a=6}]
```